# How to get Index of selected Item in ion-select

Tags: ionic2, ion-select

I am using `<ion-select>` for drop-down list and it working as expected but what I want here is **Index** of selected option from `<ion-select>`

I have used `<ion-select>` and change event like below:

```
<ion-select class="myCustomSelect" [(ngModel)]="selectedProductDD" interface="popover" (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let selectedProduct of productArray" [value] = selectedProduct.pid>{{ selectedProduct.pid }} </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

**Change Event :**

```
onSelectChange(selectedValue: any) {
   //Here I want Index also.
   //Currently I am getting selected Value.
}
```

let me know if any can help me on this!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want index only or value with index..

Comment: value with index

Comment: hmm..you would have to bind a custom object to value..cant you use `indexOf`?

Comment: Checkout the solution in ionic 4 and tweak it to Ionic 2 [Solution to get Selected Index in ion-select ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292742/10422799)

Comment: Checkout the solution in Ionic 4 and tweak it to Ionic 2 [Solution to get Selected Index in ion-select ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292742/10422799)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `*ngFor` you can also define a variable to receive que index

```
<ion-select class="myCustomSelect" [(ngModel)]="selectedProductDD" interface="popover" (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event)">
  <!-- you can also have your index by declaring a variable in ngFor that'll receive the index -->
  <ion-option *ngFor="let selectedProduct of productArray; let i = index" [value] = selectedProduct.pid>{{ selectedProduct.pid }} </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

The case here is that your declared index is inside your `ion-select` so it's not available for `onSelectChange` method. So declare a property in your .TS file

```
public myIndex: number = 0;
```

And every time a user select an option the property will receive the index

```
<!-- on selecting an option your myIndex will receive the current selected option index -->
<ion-option *ngFor="let selectedProduct of productArray; let i = index" [value]=selectedProduct.pid (ionSelect)="myIndex = i">{{ selectedProduct.pid }}</ion-option>
```

Then you can use it in your `onSelectChange()`

```
onSelectChange(selectedValue: any) {
  let index = this.myIndex;
}
```

There's another options but this is the most Angular way of doing this. Hope this helps.

Comment: above solution is not working I am getting error while selecting another option from dropdown have you test it above code ?

Comment: I am getting `Selected Index undefined`

Comment: @CodeChanger oh so srry, `myIndex` need t receive `i` not `index`

Comment: I have changed as per you update everything working fine but 1 selected value giving wrong Index any idea about that ?

Comment: The first option is giving wrong index? Try removing `= 0` when declaring myIndex.