# Ionic (ionChange) get selected index

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

So I know how to get the selected value using the ionChange event, but how do I get the selected index. For example if i was to select the 3rd value down in a dropdown how can I get the selected index (2) rather than the value selected?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55004647/5729813) is applicable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Index of selected Item in ion-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281395/how-to-get-index-of-selected-item-in-ion-select)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like ths:-

```
<ion-select placeholder="Select One">
      <ion-select-option value="id1">Value1</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="id2">Value2</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

By this when you will select any particular option, then on its change event you will get that object's id instead of the value in the controller.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do to get the id. Add a local variable to your ion-select *#selectedIndex*. After add your value like this ***[value]=[prices.w, id]***

```
<ion-select slot="end" (ionChange)="changePrice($event)" #selectIndex>
  <ion-select-option text-uppercase [value]="[prices.w, id]" *ngFor="let prices of prodData?.prices; let id = index" >{{prices.w}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

In your ts. Import ViewChild

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

After reference your local variable

```
@ViewChild('selectIndex') selectedId: ElementRef;
```

then declare your *ionChange()* function **changePrice(event)** and add the following code

```
public changePrice(event) {
const childCount = this.selectedId['el']['childElementCount'];
this.selectedId['el']['childNodes'][`${childCount}`]['defaultValue'] = event.detail.value[0];
this.selectedId['el']['shadowRoot']['children'][1]['innerHTML'] = event.detail.value[0];
this.selectedId['el']['shadowRoot']['children'][1]['innerText'] = event.detail.value[0];
console.log(event.detail.value[1]);
}
```

logs your index

```
console.log(event.detail.value[1]);
```

Hope it works fine